# Как корректно сохранить статический маршрут в /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: linux, linux-mint, интерфейс

OS: **Linux mint 18.3**
У меня есть два интерфейса:

```
and@and-work ~ $ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:61:86:bb:21:ee  
          inet addr:192.168.0.123  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::db5a:f319:4447:d570/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9736 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8492 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5750491 (5.7 MB)  TX bytes:711324 (711.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Локальная петля (Loopback)  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:25153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3476909 (3.4 MB)  TX bytes:3476909 (3.4 MB)

wlp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:5d:60:5e:99:46  
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76b:3027:84aa:90fb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1001480 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:712265 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1306197522 (1.3 GB)  TX bytes:84763529 (84.7 MB)

and@and-work ~ $
```

Через wlp6s0 я выхожу в интернет.
Через enp2s0 я выхожу в сеть предприятия.
Мне нужно, чтобы автоматически при подключении разъёма интерфейса enp2s0 у меня добавлялся следующий путь

```
route add -net 10.100.0.0/16 gw 192.168.0.1 enp2s0
```

Для этого я изменил /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp2s0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.123/24
        up route add -net 10.100.0.0/16 gw 192.168.0.1 enp2s0
        down route del -net 10.100.0.0/16 gw 192.168.0.1 enp2s0
```

Но это почему то не работает.

Comment: во-первых, надо упомянуть интерфейс как горяче-подключаемый (см. `$ man interfaces` на предмет `allow-hotplug`), во-вторых, программа *route* (вместе с остальным bарахлом типа *ifconfig*, *arp* и т.п.) не актуальна (что на практике означает: может работать некорректно либо вообще не работать) в операционной системе *gnu/linux* уже восемнадцать (!!!) лет. `ip r a 10.100.0.0/16 via 192.168.0.1` и т.д.

Comment: auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.123/24
        up ip route add 10.100.0.0/16 via 192.168.0.1
        down ip route del 10.100.0.0/16 via 192.168.0.1
Тоже не работает

Comment: не работает-то небось детектирование появления/пропадания линка, а не команды в /etc/interfaces. смотрите логи и сообщения программы *linux*.

Comment: Ну да. Если вручную команду ввести то всё работает. Но как только переткну кабель, то путь исчезает из route-таблицы. В каком файле смотреть лог? И собственно лог чего?

Comment: 1. сообщения, выдаваемые программой *linux*, и хранимые в кольцевом буфере сообщений, можно просмотреть программой *dmesg*. 2. под «логами» подразумевались в первую очередь `/var/log/messages` и `/var/log/syslog`